# How to convert an object to a string for a list search?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to search a list that contains only objects for a string input entered by the user. If an object in the list has a name that corresponds to the string input, the code should print the relevant info of the object and return it.

However, output is "0" even if I enter an item I know is on the list. I need python to recognize the objects in the list as a string so that it knows when the input is equal to one of the objects.

This is my code:

```
flavor_input = str.upper(input('What is the flavor of the cake you are looking for? '))
for var in cakeList:
     if str(var) == flavor_input:
         print('The flavor has been found')
         print(var)
         return var
    if var not in cakeList:
         print('The cake is not on the list!')
         return 0
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `cakeList` and what input are you providing that should not produce `0`?

Comment: What type are the objects in cakeList?

Comment: `if var not in cakeList` is indented underneath `for var in cakeList`, so I don't see how it could ever be true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cant write comments so, maybe trying this

```
if str.upper(var) in flavor_input:
```

it may be that the var word is not uppercase. Also i think you can just compare them raw, without the loop

```
if flavor_input in cakeList
```

hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the first item in the list and then iterate over the list inside the for loop. Your logic is faulty.

```
cakeList = ['SPAM', 'HAM']
flavor_input = str.upper(input('What is the flavor of the cake you are looking for? '))
for var in cakeList:
    if str(var) == flavor_input:
        print('The flavor has been found')
        print(var)
        break
else:
    print('The cake is not on the list!')
```

Or more simply:

```
if flavor_input in map(str,cakeList):
    print('The flavor has been found')
else:
    print('The cake is not on the list!')
```